# How can i insert some data to a cell of excel from nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, insert, updates

I would like to insert a data to a cell in excel using nodejs. Can someone help me do the same nodejs. I have to read an excel file from my nodejs code and insert data to aparticular cell of my excel sheet.
I tried a code in which the below code gives the output as shown after that how can I acess that data in v ie, john
code snippet

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(worksheet['A2']))
```

output

```
{"t":"s","v":"john","r":"<t>jon</t>","h":"john","w":"jon"}
```

fullcode - itried to insert a data to a cell of excel

```
const XLS

    X = require('xlsx');
    let workbook = XLSX.readFile('test1.xlsx');
    let sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    console.log(sheetName+'    sheetName')
    let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
    console.log(worksheet['A2']+'    worksheet a2')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(worksheet['A2']))
       worksheet['A2'].value = 'test';
      var cell = worksheet.getCell('A2');
      //cell.value = 'test';
      sheetName.getCell("A2").value = "test"
```

Comment: Which library are you using to read/write an excel file? Please include more code of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with how Pandas DataFrames are structured (basically an array of key-value pairs, with the keys being the column names), then [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json) is probably a good bet for what you're looking for. It's fairly straightforward to set-up, and should let you traverse the converted sheet and edit it, as a JSON object. Post this, you can go back to the excel file-format, using something like [json2xls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls).

```
const result = excelToJson({
    sourceFile: 'SOME-EXCEL-FILE.xlsx'
});

result.sheet1[0]["Col_Name"] = "Foo"
```

However, this may not be feasible for extremely large excel sheets, especially if it becomes inconvenient to hold the entire contents in memory. If this is the case, then copying the sheet data over line-by-line, and modifying the required row would probably be the way to go. I'm going to draw this answer to a close here because I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but if it is, I'd be glad to help out with that :)